# Restrict objects to path in Box2D

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, box2d, physics-engine

Is it possible to restrict objects in Box2D to a path?

Specifically I'd like to move cars around something like a roller coaster and use Box2D for physics and collision detection.

Would this be feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to restrict objects to paths in Box2D, yes.

Here are some ways to achieve this where the second way is closer to what you're specifically looking for:

- Using a joint. The prismatic joint (using [`b2PrismaticJointDef`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/include/box2d/b2_prismatic_joint.h)) will provide a straight line path. Example uses can be found in Box2D test bed code like [`slider_crank_1.cpp`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/testbed/tests/slider_crank_1.cpp) and [`slider_crank_2.cpp`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/testbed/tests/slider_crank_2.cpp). Meanwhile, the distance joint (`b2DistanceJointDef`), can be used to keep an object on circular paths. Similarly, other joints will restrict an object to paths according to their purpose and configuration.
- Using other objects to act like walls for the path. Examples of this can be found in the Box2D [`character_collision.cpp`](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/testbed/tests/character_collision.cpp) test bed code.